# Emptying the Google Custom Search Engine synonyms list

Tags: google-custom-search

*Note for serial question objectors: This question is about the webapp Google Custom Search Engine. It is not about creating or developing web applications.*

How can I empty my Google Custom Search Engine synonyms list https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy6Fi.png without having to delete each of the 79 pages one by one?

I've tried uploading a new empty XML file, and a single-entry one, but this does not achieve the desired result.

Unfortunately it adds to the existing list rather than replacing it. Goodness only knows who thought that was a smart idea. Or perhaps it is a bug.